# Редирект на страницу в iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Во фрейме прописан следующий код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
location.href="http://site.ru";
});
</script>
```

Этот код делает редирект на указанную страницу, но открывается она в том же фрейме. Как сделать, чтобы открывалась полноценная страница не в iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.parent.location.href="http://site.ru";
    });
</script>
```